# Neo4j / Cypher / Traversing nodes having a specific label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I'm using Neo4j Spatial plugin.

Let's suppose this basic query:

```
START c = node:carslocation('withinDistance:[2.3725963,48.892067, 34.0]') 
RETURN c
```

It returns all the cars within 34 km.

What if I want to only retrieve **race** cars (using Labels).

Without Spatial I would do:

```
MATCH (c:Race)
RETURN c
```

Now if I want **all race cars within 34km**, I would have:

```
START c = node:carslocation('withinDistance:[2.3725963,48.892067, 34.0]') 
MATCH (c:Race)
RETURN c
```

=> `Cannot add labels or properties on a node which is already bound`.
Indeed, `c` was already bound at the first line.

I don't want to have to do this:

```
START c = node:carslocation('withinDistance:[2.3725963,48.892067, 34.0]') 
MATCH (cr:Race)
WHERE cr.id = c.id
RETURN cr
```

It would force me to open all nodes, to check for the equality... => bad performance especially when the query gets more complex ( even if id is indexed).

What could be an efficient solution?

**UPDATE -------------------**

Perhaps comparing nodes only is more efficient:

```
START c = node:carslocation('withinDistance:[2.3725963,48.892067, 34.0]') 
MATCH (cr:Race)
WHERE cr = c
RETURN cr
```

Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
START c = node:carslocation('withinDistance:[2.3725963,48.892067, 34.0]') 
WHERE 'Race' in labels(c)
RETURN c
```

You basically lookup all nodes within the given region and then filter them if their labels contain `Race`.

Comment: Nice! :) So is it more efficient than the second solution I wrote in my "update" section?

Comment: It depends on the number of nodes found by the spatial query versus the number of nodes having the Race label. The query I've sketched does a index query and looks up all the nodes referenced by the result of the index query. So I consider it being more efficient in most cases.

Comment: If you do `START c=node:carslocation .... MATCH (cr:Race) WHERE ....` you're doing the index query, load all nodes for its result *AND* look  up all nodes carrying the `Race` label globally.